# Yii2 Checkbox field cannot be checked

Tags: yii2, field, checked

This is my input script, It is blocked I cant check it and whene i set the attribute value to Active i got the error" id permission must be integer "

```
    <?php foreach(Permission::find()->all() as $key => $perm){ ?>                       

        <tr class="unread selected">
        <td>
     <div class="ckbox ckbox-theme">                                                     
    <?= $form->field($modelUserPermission, 'id_permission')->checkbox(['id' => $perm['id'],'name' => $perm['id'],'label'=>"", 'value' =>"1" ]  ); ?>

    <label for=<?=   $perm['id'] ; ?> ></label>
 </div>
                                                    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="media">

            <div class="media-body">
               <!-- <h4 class="text-primary">John Kribo</h4>-->
                <p class="email-summary"><strong><?=   $perm['description'] ; ?> </strong>    </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

& my model's rules

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id_user', 'id_permission'], 'required'],
            [['id_user', 'id_permission'], 'integer'],
            [['date_fin'], 'safe'],
            [['id_permission'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Permission::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id_permission' => 'id']],
            [['id_user'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id_user' => 'id']],
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Can you update your question with model file rules?

Comment: May be `'value' =>"1"` to `'value' =>1`

Comment: @ManikandanS i add it above

Comment: Try removing `id_permission` attribute from being integer. Test if there are any differences.

Comment: @Afaf Thanks for adding model rules method in question. Please try to use checkbox value as integer instead of string similiar like Insane Skull comment above.